# Reset navigation stack

Tags: react-native-navigation

I would like to reset the navigation stack in wix-react-native-navigation. But couldn't find the API in the docs. It's okay to be in v1 or in v2.

I could find `this.props.navigator.resetTo`, but this only takes one screen. But I would like to reset the stack with more than one screen. With/without modifying the root.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

> popToRoot(params = {})

you can have look to the [screen API docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=poptorootparams-) if you need more details